# Regex to match certain pattern of number combinations

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking making a regex in php that gets data from the following format:

```
"1,2,3;7,1,3;1" returns an $matches array with "(1,2,3,7,1,3,1)"

"1" returns an $matches with "(1)"

"1;1;3;5;7;10;999" returns an $matches array with "(1,1,3,5,7,10,999)"

"1,1,1;2,5;3,4" doesn't pass since numbers are repeating within semicolon boundaries

"2,3,4;5,;" doesn't pass since it doesn't satisfy the format.
```

(Quotes in the examples are there to make them easier to read; they should not appear in the real results.)

The format is digit numbers separated by either commas or semicolons and within semicolons they don't repeat each other. ***It should not accept any other format.***

I tried `/(^(\d{1,3})$)|(([0-9]+)([,|;]{1}[0-9]+)+)/` but it didn't work.
I also tried `/[0-9]+([,|;]{1}[0-9]+)+/` but it didn't worked either. When I got the $matches array it didn't have the values I needed as depicted above.

I'm doing this in **PHP 5.2**.
Thanks.

Comment: "It didn't work" isn't an explanation of the problem. *Why* didn't it work? *What specificially* didn't work?

Comment: Added a description of why it didn't worked, sorry.

Comment: You don't need to use `{1}` - all characters match a single instance, unless a quantifier is added.

Comment: I'm not sure you can avoid repeating characters using regex. A script-based solution might be necessary here.

Comment: While it is [sort of](http://rubular.com/r/nKjpghZxUc) possible with a regex, in this case you may be better off using a few lines of code: split by semicolon, get the sets, and check all sets do not have repeating numbers. Should be pretty simple.

Comment: So regex is not the way to go?

Comment: @link_boy - It can be used to validate the format, as long as the format is simple, but I'd go with Jack's solution. Although it is longer it might prove to be easier to maintain - specially if you will have additional requirements (for example - average of numbers, etc).

Comment: @Kobi I see. I was planning on validating each array value with further validation for ranges and other criteria that I will be using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular problem has too much logic for regular expressions to be practical; this is how you could solve it with regular code:

```
// reduction function - keeps merging comma separated arguments
// until there's a duplicate or invalid item
function join_unique(&$result, $item)
{
    if ($result === false) {
        return false;
    }

    $items = explode(',', $item);
    $numbers = array_filter($items, 'is_numeric');

    if (count($items) != count($numbers)) {
        return false;
    }

    $unique = array_unique($numbers);

    if (count($unique) != count($numbers)) {
        return false;
    }

    return array_merge($result, $numbers);
}

// main function - parse a string of comma / semi-colon separated values
function parse_nrs($str)
{
    return array_reduce(explode(';', $str), 'join_unique', array());
}

var_dump(parse_nrs('1,2,3;7,1,3;1'));
var_dump(parse_nrs('1'));
var_dump(parse_nrs('1;1;3;5;7;10;999'));
var_dump(parse_nrs('1,1,1;2,5;3,4'));
var_dump(parse_nrs('2,3,4;5,;'));
```

Output:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "7"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "7"
  [5]=>
  string(2) "10"
  [6]=>
  string(3) "999"
}
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

See also: [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/array_reduce) [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique)

Comment: `"2,3,4;5,;"` is giving me   `[0]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
  [5]=>
  string(0) ""`

Comment: doing a foreach search if empty would solve the problem? as a final validation?

Comment: @link_boy Should be fixed now. It returns `false` in that case. I'm checking if each item is numeric, which is better than testing empty, but you could test for empty too.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is my fourth day using php and I'm still learning new things. I didn't know there were that many operations available with arrays. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to do this in a single step.  First you will need to check for the requirement of numbers repeating within a semicolon boundary, and then if it passes that checks split the string.

For example:

```
if (!preg_match('/\b(\d+),[^;]*\b\1\b/', $string)) {
    $matches = preg_split('/[,;]/', $string);
} else {
    $matches = NULL;
}
```

Ideone: http://ideone.com/Y8xf1N

Comment: You may want another `\b` - `/\b(\d+),[^;]*\b\1\b/`, or you might match `9,99`.

Comment: @F.J "1,2,3,4;1,2,34;1;2;1,143535" didn't passed on my side.

Comment: Wouldn't `/\b(\d+),\1\b/` do as well?

Comment: @Jack That would work as long as the matching numbers are always guaranteed to be consecutive, but I'm not sure if that is a valid assumption.

Comment: @Kobi "2,3,4;5,;" error case gives me an PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected, it should not match anything

Comment: @link_boy - Hmm... What? What did I do!? You should update the question I you have new requirements.

Comment: @Kobi Sorry, I specified that it shouldn't accept any other format :/, I will highlight that part.